# Default value for Yes/No field

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

Struggling with an extremely easy issue, however, due to the lack of a more specific error message from ADO, I can't figure it out.

I need to add a new column in a table using SQL, the column type is a YESNO, however, I also want to set it's default value to TRUE|YES or whatever the brilliant engineers thought to name it ... this is what I have:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME
ADD COLUMN VISIBLE YESNO DEFAULT YES; /* the engine complains, 1 is also not ok, true is not ok, what is OK? */
```

If I remove everything after **default** the SQL will be executed as expected...

Thank you!

**EDIT**:

Just in case someone else hits this "wall", here's my final SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME
ADD COLUMN VISIBLE YESNO -1;
```

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786021/ado-database-table-boolean-column,  Maybe try -1.

Comment: thank you @Dampsquid, but I had already looked at that, before asking the question, I've hit at least 2 dozen websites...

Comment: Please note that the sql statement shown under edit will run in MS Access, but it will not set a default value for the field (column). I have tested with Access 2000 & 2010 with a connection and the query design window.

Comment: Okay, I think I have figured this out. Access drops the last word if it is not relevant so `alter table table2 add column colb integer unicorn` will run, but the unicorn is mythical and will have no effect, just like a -1 or 0 appended to the end of the statement without any qualifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to execute against a connection to use Default, eg:

```
s = "ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD COLUMN VISIBLE YESNO DEFAULT true"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute s
```

-1 is fine, too. If you want to display a checkbox, you will need VBA.

Comment: +1 and accepted, thank you, I needed to use "...YESNO -1", basically skip "DEFAULT" word... why do some people need to reinvent boolean fields? beats me...

Comment: Thanks for the vote. I am pretty surprised that -1 without keyword DEFAULT sets a default value in MS Access. It certainly does not work for me.

Comment: well, it does, it seems that -1 is equal to true, weird stuff... see my edit

Comment: -1 is a 16bit unsigned integer with all 1s which is the usual representation of True compared with 0 which is a 16bit unsigned integer of all 0 which is the representation of False.  Probably anything other than 0 would be treated as true, which is the traditional programming approach

Comment: The point is not that -1 equals true but that an unqualified true appended to an SQL statement is taken as a default value. It must be some odd quirk of Delphi, because I cannot see it working in any version of Access.

Comment: @Remou whatever it is, I'm happy it's over (: it works using ADO and ms access 2007...